# android: a tab host where each tab has an unread count badge

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, android-widget, android-tabhost

I need to write a tab bar where each of the tabspecs has an indicator view that contains a changable numeric badge.
imagine a tabbed news reader where each tab has it's own unread count

What I did is create an xml layout for the tab inidicator, inflated it in code and associated it with the tabspec like so:
tab_indicator.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="5dip">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/tab_selector_friends"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:text="2" 
            android:layout_width="10dip" android:layout_height="10dip" 
            android:textColor="@color/white_text"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:typeface="monospace"
            android:paddingLeft="1dip" android:paddingRight="1dip"
            android:textSize="10dip" android:gravity="center" android:background="@drawable/temp_red_badge_big" />

    </FrameLayout>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Friends" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my tab widget (oncreate metod of MyTabWidget.java):

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_menu);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TodayActivity.class);
    Resources resources = this.getResources();  
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(resources.getString(R.string.today));
    View specIndicatorView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    specIndicatorView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
    spec.setIndicator(specIndicatorView);
    spec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

There are several issues with this approach:

1. It is extremely convoluted and hard to maintain
2. It does not afford me the flexibility I require, i.e. change the value of the badge
3. It is very hard to design it in a way that looks good
4. It just seems like it's too complicated an approach

My question is, can you suggest a better way to do this? is there a different approach I didn't consider?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things.

Use a RelativeLayout. This may help with issue 3 because it allows more control over where these elements are placed in the layout.

You should be using android:id attributes with all or your xml elements. That way you can set your view in the xml but still make changes to it programmatically, which should help with issue 2. For instance, if you were to give your TextView an id attribute, you would not need to hard code the text attribute.

In your xml,

```
<TextView android:id="count"
...
/>
```

And in your java,

```
TextView count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
count.setText(friendsCount);
```

In general, I don't think it's *that* convoluted, but it can certainly be improved upon.